# Date compare format

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm creating a datepicker (Materialize) system into my webapp and I'm facing to a weird problem with date comparaison (see below). I would like to warn the user that if he want a date witch is less than 48hours, he will pay more. To do that I wrote a script to check the changes of the input start_date.

```
('#event_start_at_date').on('change', function(){ 
  var limit = moment().add(2, 'days').format("DD/MM/YYYY")
  if($('#event_d_script').val() != "true"){
    if ( $(this).val() <= moment() ){
      // the date is impossible
      $(this).val(date_min)
    } else if ( $(this).val() <= limit ) { 
      // the date is less than 48h from today
      $('#date_warning').slideDown();
      if($('#event_urgent').val() == "false"){
        var amount = parseFloat($('#event_price').val()) + 10
        $('#offer_footer_price_val').text(amount);
        $('#event_price').val(amount)
        $('#event_urgent').val("true");
        $('#event_urgent_checkbox').attr('checked', true);
      }
    } else{
      // the date is more than 48h from today
      $('#date_warning').slideUp();
      if($('#event_urgent').val() == "true"){
        // The previous date was urgent
        var amount = parseFloat($('#event_price').val()) - 10
        $('#offer_footer_price_val').text(amount);
        $('#event_price').val(amount);
        $('#event_urgent').val("false");
        $('#event_urgent_checkbox').attr('checked', false);
      }
    }
    if($('#event_end_at_date').val() <= $(this).val() ){
      // The end can't be before the start
      $('#event_end_at_date').val($(this).val())
    }
  }
});
```

My error = The comparison is made only on the day, not on the full date.

For example, if today is November 12, the increase is applied until the November 14. But also all the days before the 14 for the others months (ex: 12 dec).

I thing that's an error of date format, but I cannot fix it

Comment: I thing your error is about the format of your date

Comment: `$(this).val() <= moment()` compares a string (possibly in YYY-MM-DD format but maybe not) and a moment object where *toString* is in some unspecified format, which is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at the code to closely, it seems as though your error is most likely because your format DD//MM//YYYY.

Your date calculations, whether they are bigger or smaller, are calculated mathematically, as though they were just numbers. i.e. 02/05/1995 is simply calculated like 02051995.

So your unexpected behaviour is because if you imagine, you are assuming the DAY is the biggest unit, meaning a change in a day, is technically greater numerically, than a change in a YEAR, because your years are the smallest unit and your days are the largest.

ie. 03/10/2018 will be greater than 02/12/2018 because 03102018 is greater than 02122018.

Change your formatting when doing calculations to, YYYY-MM-DD to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your solution @cmprogram. It's the more simplest and effective

Comment: *"Your date calculations, whether they are bigger or smaller, are calculated mathematically, as though they were just numbers. i.e. 02/05/1995 is simply calculated like 02051995."* No, that's incorrect. They're compared **as strings**. However, (@stigGaret too) the *solution* works, because those strings compare in a date-like way (years are most significant, then months, then days).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Could you provide me the documentation that covers that? I'd really appreciate if we could make my answer more accurate, and I just want to check where this is found. I'm currently searching also, but if you know exactly where, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @cmprogram - Well, `$(this).val()` returns a string, and `.format` returns a string, so the usual meaning of `string < string` applies, which is a lexicographic (loosely, alphabetic) comparison of the strings.

Comment: "*Without looking at the code to closely…*" is not a good way to start an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. You're being inconsistent with your value types, for instance comparing a *string* with a Moment instance:

   ```
   if ( $(this).val() <= moment() ) {
   ```
2. You're comparing things lexicographically (that is, as text) that you should compare numerically, such as here:

   ```
   } else if ( $(this).val() <= limit ) {
   ```

Instead, use a data type you can meaningfully compare. In this case, I'd use Moment instances, since comparing them will coerce them to numbers (milliseconds since The Epoch);

```
if ( moment($(this).val()) < moment() ) {
```

and

```
var limit = moment().add(2, 'days'); // No `format`
```

and

```
} else if ( moment($(this).val()) <= limit ) {
```

If you want to disregard the time aspect of those datetimes and just compare dates, you can use [`startOf("day")`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) to set the various Moment instances to midnight, e.g.:

```
if ( moment($(this).val().startOf("day")) < moment().startOf("day") ) {
```

and

```
var limit = moment().add(2, 'days').startOf("day");
```

and

```
} else if ( moment($(this).val()).startOf("day") <= limit ) {
```

Comment: Hi @T.J, thanks for taking time to respond to me. I implement your solution to test it

Comment: I cannot use your solution, I don't know why. So I've implemented the @cmprogram one. But thanks for your advices